# How to render context values in generic list and detail views

Tags: django, django-models, django-generic-views

I have a base template file (shared.html) contains Header and Footer, using on every page. I have some dynamic values from database in shared.html (e.g: Phone number, address, logos) and showing perfectly on index view page, but not showing on any of the generic views page.

Please guide me how to do this to show all the dynamic values on every generic view page.

Index view:

```
def index(request):
    # Display all the Dynamic values form models
    num = TopBar.objects.get()
    addressISD = AddressIslamabad.objects.all()
    addressRWP = AddressRawalpindi.objects.all()
    alt = Logo.objects.all()
    YLP7Text = WhyLP7Text.objects.all()
    PMBG = BGimages.objects.all()
    lp7Features = LP7features.objects.all()
    locate = Locations.objects.all()
    events = Events.objects.all()
    memberLogo = LP7MembersLogo.objects.all()
    testi = LP7Testimonials.objects.all()
    promo = Promotions.objects.all()


    c = context = ({
    'topBarNumber': num,
    'addressISD': addressISD,
    'addressRWP': addressRWP,
    'altText': alt,
    'YLP7Text': YLP7Text,
    'BG': PMBG,
    'featuresLP7': lp7Features,
    'LC': locate,
    'evt': events,
    'memLogo': memberLogo,
    'testi': testi,
    'promo': promo

    })

    # Render the HTML template index.html
    return render(request, 'index.html', c )
```

Generic View:

```
# Display the detail and generic views
class EventListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Events


class EventDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Events


class PromotionListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Promotions

class PromotionDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Promotions
```

Comment: why you are doint this ? `c = context = (#blahblah)` it could be a simple dictionary

Comment: Because context have much values to show on index page, By the way I can simply write return render(request, 'index.html', context=context )

Question: How can I use all the context values in generic view page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can write a [**`custom context processor`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors) for this. For example:

```
def custom_context_processor(request):
    # Display all the Dynamic values form models
    num = TopBar.objects.get()
    addressISD = AddressIslamabad.objects.all()
    addressRWP = AddressRawalpindi.objects.all()
    alt = Logo.objects.all()
    YLP7Text = WhyLP7Text.objects.all()
    PMBG = BGimages.objects.all()
    lp7Features = LP7features.objects.all()
    locate = Locations.objects.all()
    events = Events.objects.all()
    memberLogo = LP7MembersLogo.objects.all()
    testi = LP7Testimonials.objects.all()
    promo = Promotions.objects.all()

    context = {
        'topBarNumber': num,
        'addressISD': addressISD,
        'addressRWP': addressRWP,
        'altText': alt,
        'YLP7Text': YLP7Text,
        'BG': PMBG,
        'featuresLP7': lp7Features,
        'LC': locate,
        'evt': events,
        'memLogo': memberLogo,
        'testi': testi,
        'promo': promo
    }
    return { 'common_content': context }
```

And then add it to `CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` like this:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        # ...
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'path.to.custom_context_processor',
                # rest of the context processors
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

And use this context processor in header and footer like this:

```
{% for key, value in common_content.items %}
     {{ key }} {{ value }}
{% endfor %}
```

Finally, as it is making a lot of DB query, you can use [**`template fragment caching`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/cache/#template-fragment-caching) to reduce DB hits.

Comment: Thank you very much all of you for helping me especially Ruddra . 
This is exactly what I need for best solution and now its working on every page

Answer (score 0):

In your generic view,

```
class PromotionDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Promotions
    template_name = 'promotions/promotions.html' #<app_name>/<model>_<viewtype>.html
    context_object_name = 'Promotions'
```

in your **promotions.html** do this

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html'%}
{% block content %}
    {% for promotion in Promotions%}
    <article class="media content-section">
        <img class="rounded-circle article-img" src="{{ promotion.logos.url }}">
        <div class="media-body">
            <div class="article-metadata">
                <a class="mr-2" href="{% url 'user-post' promotion.Addresses %}">{{ promotion.Name }}</a>
                <small class="text-muted">{{ promotion.Date_posted|date:"d F, Y" }}</small>
            </div>
            <p class="article-content">{{ promotion.Phone_Number}}</p>
        </div>
    </article>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: I already have this kind of code in shared.html , I just want to fetch this data in promotion_list.html.

Comment: you need to first pass promotion context in your generic view like I indicated above, you can't fetch items in the template without first passing them in the context.

Answer (score 0):

In `GenericViews` you can override the `get_context_data` method in order to set the `context` that you need in your templates.

You can do something like this:

```
class EventListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Events
    # We could explicitly tell the view which template 
    # to use by adding a template_name attribute to the view, 
    # but in the absence of an explicit template Django will infer one
    # from the object’s name
    # template_name = 'path/template.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # Update context with data needed
        context['foo'] = 'bar'
        context['foo_2'] = 'bar_2'
        return context
```

In your template you will then be able to access the `context` as:

```
{% for object in object_list %}
    {{ object.foo }}
    {{ object.foo_2 }}
{% endfor %}
```

For `DetailViews` you can override the same `get_context_data` method, but will not need a loop in the template.

You can read more about this in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#generic-display-views), these examples are quite elaborate.